# Join table twice - on two different columns of the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, foreign-keys, left-join

I have a very confusing database with a table that holds two values I need in a separate table. Here is my issue:

```
Table1
- id

Table2
- id
- table1_id
- table3_id_1
- table3_id_2

Table3
- id
- value
```

I need to go from table1 and do a join that would give me back the value from `table3` in two separate columns. So I want something like this:

```
table1.id | table2.id | table2.table3_id_1 | table2.table3_id_2 | X | Y
```

Where `X` and `Y` are the values for the row connected by `table3_id_1` and `table3_id_2` respectively.

Possibly make them variables or something so I can filter them in a `WHERE` clause as well?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.table1_id
     , t2.id          AS table2_id
     , t2.table3_id_1
     , t2.table3_id_2
     , t31.value      AS x
     , t32.value      AS y
FROM   table2 t2
LEFT   JOIN table3 t31 ON t31.id = t2.table3_id_1
LEFT   JOIN table3 t32 ON t32.id = t2.table3_id_2;
```

There is no need to involve `table1`. `table2` has all you need - assuming there is a [foreign key constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-fk.html) guaranteeing referential integrity (all `t2.table1_id` are actually present in `table1`). Else you may want to join to `table1`, thereby selecting only rows also present in `table1`.

I use [**`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`** (and not `[INNER] JOIN`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) to join to both instances of `table3` for a similar reason: it is unclear whether referential integrity is guaranteed - and whether any of the key columns can be `NULL`. An `[INNER] JOIN` would drop rows from the result where no match is found. I assume you would rather display such rows with a `NULL` value for any missing `x` or `y`.

`table3.id` needs to be `UNIQUE`, or we might multiply rows with several matches from each `LEFT JOIN`:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

Answer (score 10):

If you join a table several times, use aliases to distinguish them:

```
SELECT table1.id,table2.id,table2.table3_id_1,table2.table3_id_2,t3_1.id,t3_2.id
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.table1_id
JOIN table3 t3_1 ON table2.table3_id_1=t3_1.id
JOIN table3 t3_2 ON table2.table3_id_2=t3_2.id
WHERE ... t3_1.id=... AND ... t3_2.id=...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select t1.id as table1_id, 
    t2.id as table2_id, 
    t2.table3_id_1, 
    t2.table3_id_2,
    t3_1.value as X, 
    t3_2.value as Y
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id
inner join Table3 t3_1 on t2.table3_id_1 = t3_1.id
inner join Table3 t3_2 on t2.table3_id_2 = t3_2.id
where t3_1.value = 'some_value'
    or t3_2.value = 'some_other_value'
```