# Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have 3 tables:

```
users(id, account_balance)
grocery(user_id, date, amount_paid)
fishmarket(user_id, date, amount_paid)
```

Both `fishmarket` and `grocery` tables may have multiple occurrences for the same user_id with different dates and amounts paid or have nothing at all for any given user.
When I try the following query:

```
SELECT
     t1."id" AS "User ID",
     t1.account_balance AS "Account Balance",
     count(t2.user_id) AS "# of grocery visits",
     count(t3.user_id) AS "# of fishmarket visits"
FROM users t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN grocery t2 ON (t2.user_id=t1."id") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fishmarket t3 ON (t3.user_id=t1."id") 
GROUP BY t1.account_balance,t1.id
ORDER BY t1.id
```

It produces an incorrect results: `"1", "12", "12"`.
But when I try to `LEFT JOIN` to just one table it produces a correct results for either `grocery` or `fishmarket` visits, which are `"1", "3", "4"`.

What am I doing wrong here?
I am using PostgreSQL 9.1.

Answer (score 73):

Joins are processed left to right (unless parentheses dictate otherwise). If you `LEFT JOIN` (or just `JOIN`, similar effect) three groceries to one user you get 3 rows (**1 x 3**). If you then join 4 fishmarkets for the same user, you get 12 (**3 x 4**) rows, *multiplying* the previous count in the result, not *adding* to it, like you may have hoped for.
Thereby multiplying the visits for groceries and fishmarkets alike.

You can make it work like this:

```sql
SELECT u.id
     , u.account_balance
     , g.grocery_visits
     , f.fishmarket_visits
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, count(*) AS grocery_visits
   FROM   grocery
   GROUP  BY user_id
   ) g ON g.user_id = u.id
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, count(*) AS fishmarket_visits
   FROM   fishmarket
   GROUP  BY user_id
   ) f ON f.user_id = u.id
ORDER  BY u.id;
```

To get aggregated values for one or few users, *correlated subqueries* [like @Vince provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464247/939860) are just fine. For a whole table or major parts of it, it is (much) more efficient to aggregate the n-tables and join to the result *once*. This way, we also do not need another `GROUP BY` in the outer query.

`grocery_visits` and `fishmarket_visits` are **`NULL`** for users without any related entries in the respective tables. If you need **`0`** instead (or any arbitrary number), use [**`COALESCE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) in the outer `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT u.id
     , u.account_balance
     , COALESCE(g.grocery_visits   , 0) AS grocery_visits
     , COALESCE(f.fishmarket_visits, 0) AS fishmarket_visits
FROM   ...
```

Answer (score 15):

For your original query, if you take away the group by to look at the pre-grouped result, you'll see why the counts your were receiving were created.

Perhaps the following query utilizing subqueries would achieve your intended result:

```
SELECT
 t1."id" AS "User ID",
 t1.account_balance AS "Account Balance",
 (SELECT count(*) FROM grocery     t2 ON (t2.user_id=t1."id")) AS "# of grocery visits",
 (SELECT count(*) FROM fishmarket  t3 ON (t3.user_id=t1."id")) AS "# of fishmarket visits"
FROM users t1
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because when the user table joins to the grocery table, there are 3 records matched. Then each of those three records matches with the 4 records in fishmarket, producing 12 records. You need subqueries to get what you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT
     t1."id" AS "User ID",
     t1.account_balance AS "Account Balance",
     Sum(Case When t2.user_id is null then 0 else 1 end) AS "# of grocery visits",
     Sum(Case When t3.user_id is null then 0 else 1 end) AS "# of fishmarket visits"
FROM users t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN grocery t2 ON (t2.user_id=t1."id") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fishmarket t3 ON (t3.user_id=t1."id") 
GROUP BY t1.account_balance,t1.id
ORDER BY t1.id
```

The above will also allow you to add additional criteria as needed