# How to properly use inner join in SQL when I have to join a table twice?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Note: The actual schema isn't male/female, but some other criteria. I'm just using male/female for this example to make it easier to understand.

I have a table "users", which contains a column user_name and user_gender. The gender can be "M" or "F".

The problem is that I have another table, "messages", that has a column for "sender" and "receiver". These columns contains user_name in each row.

How can I use INNER JOIN so that I can get messages where only males send to females?

I know easily how to specify it once, binding users.user_name to "sender" or "receiver" but not both.

To expand on my question, how do see which top 10 pairs where a male sent the most messages to a female? Note, this means unique A/B pairs, so I want to return cases where a guy sends a single female a ton of messages, not when a guy spams a lot of messages to different females.

Comment: Look into [self-join tables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm) where Users will be joined twice to Messages table: one on receiver column and the other one on sender column. Then condition receiver and sender columns with WHERE clause on M or F condition.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267929/whats-the-best-way-to-join-on-the-same-table-twice or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710271/join-table-twice-on-two-different-columns-of-the-same-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of your `messages` table as a "cross table" connecting two rows in the `users` table. When you join to a table like that, give `users` two different aliases, and refer to them in your join conditions, like this:

```
select *
from messages msg
join users m on msg.sender = m.user_id AND m.user_gender='M'
join users f on msg.receiver = f.user_id AND f.user_gender='F'
```

With this skeleton in hand, you should be able to figure out the rest of your query:

- Use `GROUP BY` to group by `m.user_id, f.user_id`, and `count(*)` to count
- Order by `COUNT(*)` to get the highest sender+receiver pairs at the top
- Use `LIMIT` to grab the top ten pairs.